# Fundamental theorem of calculus for complex analysis, proof

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I've been trying to verify/fill in the details of my book's proof of the complex FTOC, but have gotten stuck. Here are the statement and proof: If a continuous function $f$ has a primitive $F$ in $\Omega$, and $\gamma$ is a curve in $\Omega$ that begins at $w_{1}$ and ends at $w_{2}$, then $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz = F(w_{2}) - F(w_{1})$.

Here, a primitive for $f$ on $\Omega$ is a function $F$ that is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and such that $F'(z)=f(z)$ for all $z\in \Omega$, where that derivative is meant to be the complex derivative. Also, $\gamma$ being smooth means that any of its parametrizations $z:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuously differentiable.

**Proof:** Suppose we have such a parametrization, and $z(a)=w_{1},z(b)=w_{2}$. then using the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz &= \int_{a}^{b}f(z(t))z'(t)\,dt \\
&= \int_{a}^{b}F'(z(t))z'(t)\,dt \\
&= \int_{a}^{b}\frac{d}{dt}F(z(t))\,dt \\
&= F(z(b)) - F(z(a))
\end{align*}

I'm having trouble with the 3rd and 4th equalities in the above string. First, $F'$ means the complex derivative. We had a theorem earlier that said for any function $g:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic at some $z_{0}$, $g'(z_{0})=\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}(z_{0})$, where we defined the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$. Let $m,n$ be the component functions of $z$, i.e. $m,n:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $z(t)=m(t)+i n(t)$ for all $t\in [a,b]$. Similarly, let $U,V:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ denote the component functions of $F$.

Then 
\begin{align*}
F'(z(t))z'(t)
&= \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(z(t))
   \left[\frac{d}{dt}m(t) + i\frac{d}{dt}n(t)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(z(t)) 
                    - i\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(z(t))\right]
   \left[\frac{d}{dt}m(t) + i\frac{d}{dt}n(t)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\left[\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} 
                          + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}\right]
   +i\left[\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} 
           + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right]\right)
   \left[\frac{d}{dt}m(t) + i\frac{d}{dt}n(t)\right]
\end{align*}
On the other hand, I'm not sure how to compute $\frac{d}{dt}F(z(t))$ using the chain rule. I'd be able to do it if I considered $F$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I've tried guessing that the notational convention is 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}F(z(t)) &= \frac{d}{dt}U(z(t)) + i \frac{d}{dt} V(z(t))
\end{align*}
where $U(z(t)),V(z(t))$ are to be computed using the multivariable(real) chain rule, but that gave me something different from what I got for $F'(z(t))z'(t)$ above.

For the fourth equality, where the FTOC is supposed to be used, I'm not sure how to parse it. The FTOC that I know is for functions $:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Any hints, insight, or more detail are very much appreciated.

Comment: the book is Stein & Shakarchi's Complex Analysis, from the Princeton lecture series

Comment: The fourth equality should at least be clear: $\int \frac{d}{dt} F(z(t)) dt = \int \frac{d}{dt} U(z(t)) dt +i \int \frac{d}{dt} V(z(t)) dt$

Comment: Also your guess about the notational convention is correct, so your computation should work out.

Comment: Ok, the third line in your computation looks wrong to me.  Also, you will need to use the Cauchy Riemann equations in your computation.  If you still can't get it, let me know.

Comment: @Tim kinsella Thanks so much. Yes, the third line was incorrect, and the CR equations were exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 13):

For functions $f,g:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, the chain rule applies

> Let $f:U\to V$ be complex differentiable at $z_0$, and let $g:V\to\mathbb C$ be complex differentiable at $w_0=f(z_0)$. Then $g\circ f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ and $(g\circ f)'(z_0) = g'(w_0)f'(z_0)$.

We can also replace $f$ by a continuously differentiable curve $\gamma$ in $V$, and we still get $(g\circ\gamma)'(x_0) = g'(\gamma(x_0))\gamma'(x_0)$

Now assume $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C$ is continuous and has a primitive $F$, and that $\gamma$ is a piecewise continuously differentiable curve in $\Omega$.
The integral of $f$ along a curve is defined as
$$
\int_\gamma f\,dz  = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt
$$
If $x_0<\dots<x_n$ denote the points such that $\gamma$ is continuously differentiable on each $[x_{i-1},x_i]$, then the right side of this equation is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt
$$
We noticed that this is equal to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (F\circ\gamma)'(t)\,dt
$$
which, by definition, is equal to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \mathrm{Re}(F\circ\gamma)'(t)\,dt + i \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \mathrm{Im}(F\circ\gamma)'(t)\,dt
$$
Since maps from the reals to Euclidean space are differentiated coordinatewise, we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (\mathrm{Re}F\circ\gamma)'(t)\,dt + i \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (\mathrm{Im}F\circ\gamma)'(t)\,dt
$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, this is equal to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Re}F(\gamma(x_i))-\mathrm{Re}F(\gamma(x_{i-1})) + i\mathrm{Im}F(\gamma(x_i)) - i\mathrm{Im}F(\gamma(x_{i-1}))
$$
which can be simplified to
$$
F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a))
$$