# Show $\int_{\gamma}fg'dz=f(\beta)g(\beta)-f(\alpha)g(\alpha)-\int_{\gamma}f'gdz$

Tags: complex-analysis

> let $G$ be an open set in $\Bbb C$ and let $f,g:G\to \Bbb C$ be analytic functions. Show that if $\gamma :[a,b]\to G$ is a rectifiable path with $\gamma(a)=\alpha,\gamma(b)=\beta$ then
>   $$\int_{\gamma}fg'dz=f(\beta)g(\beta)-f(\alpha)g(\alpha)-\int_{\gamma}f'gdz$$

This looks like the integration by parts formula in Calculus.

I tried to compute the integral $\int_{\gamma}f'gdz=\int_{a}^bf'g\gamma'(t)dt$, but I have no idea about how to conclude the result from the calculation.

Could anyone kindly help? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [complex version of the Barrow's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958774/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-for-complex-analysis-proof) with the integral
$$\int_{\gamma}(fg)'dz = \int_{\gamma}(fg'+f'g)dz.$$

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts is the correct approach.
It becomes more apparent if you define two functions
$$
 F, G : [a, b] \to \mathbb C, \\
  F(t) = f(\gamma(t)), \quad G(t) = g(\gamma(t))
$$
Then, starting with the definition of $\int_{\gamma} f g'\, dz$,
$$
\int_{\gamma} f g'\, dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\,  g'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \, dt = 
\int_a^b F(t) G'(t) \, dt \\
= F(b)G(b) - F(a)G(a) - \int_a^b F'(t) G(t) \, dt \\
= f(\beta)g(\beta)-f(\alpha)g(\alpha) - \int_a^b f'(\gamma(t))  \gamma'(t) \,  g(\gamma(t))\, dt \\
= f(\beta)g(\beta)-f(\alpha)g(\alpha) - \int_{\gamma} f' g\, dz
$$