# Identity theorem. Calculate $f$ using $f'$

Tags: complex-analysis

Supose $f\in\mathcal{H}(D(0,2))$. If $f'(1/n) = \frac{1}{n} e^{1/n^2}$, calculate $f(i) - f(-i)$.

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

My first attemp was prove that $f'(z)=ze^{z^2}$ in $D(0,2)$ using the identity theorem.

If $w_n = \frac{1}{n} \in D(0,2)$, it verifies: 
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} w_n = 0 \\ 0\in D(0,2) \\ w_n \not= 0 \ \forall n \end{array} \right.$$

If $g(z) = ze^{z^2}$, it verifies that $f'(1/n) = g(1/n)$.

Using the identity theorem, follows $$f'(z) = g(z) \  \forall z \in D(0,2)$$

But I don't know how to calculate $f(i)-f(-i)$ using $f'(z)$

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you show some context (what theorems you know, what you have tried, similar problems that you have solved) so that we can tailor our answers to something that will be useful for you

Comment: My first attemp was prove that $f'(z)=ze^{z^2}$ in $D(0,2)$ using the identity theorem. 

If $w_n = \frac{1}{n} \in D(0,2)$, it verifies: 
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} w_n = 0 \\ 0\in D(0,2) \\ w_n \not= 0 \ \forall n \end{array} \right.$$


If $g(z) = ze^{z^2}$, it verifies that $f'(1/n) = g(1/n)$. 

Using the identity theorem, follows $$f'(z) = g(z) \  \forall z \in D(0,2)$$

But I don't know how to calculate $f(i)-f(-i)$ using $f'(z)$

Comment: TL;DR, but can you not possibly integrate $f'(z)$ to obtain $f(z)$, then sub in $f(i)$, $f(-i)$, and subtract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have proved that $f'(z)=ze^{z^2}$.
This means that $f(z)=\frac12e^{z^2}+C$ for some complex constant $C$.
(Just like in analysis over the reals, it's enough to guess one integral function, as integral functions are unique up to additive constants.)

You don't know what $C$ is, but you don't need to, since it cancels out:
$$
f(i)-f(-i)
=
(\frac12e^{i^2}+C)
-
(\frac12e^{(-i)^2}+C)
=
\frac12e^{-1}
-
\frac12e^{-1}
=
0.
$$

Alternatively, since your function is analytic, you could calculate the path integral of the derivative from $-i$ to $i$ to get the difference of the values.
In that approach the constant never even appears.

More details on this alternative approach:
You can define a function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ by $g(t)=f(it)$.
You can find $g'(t)$ in terms of $f'$ and the use the fundamental theorem of calculus to find $g(1)-g(-1)=\int_{-1}^1g'(t)dt$.
In fact, any path between the two points will do, but integrating along the imaginary axis will be easiest.
For more details, please ask a new question or see [this question on the fundamental theorem of calculus in the complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/958774/166535).

Comment: I don't understand the another approach. Can you detail more this?

Comment: @J.García Done.