# Evaluate $\int_\beta \frac{\cos(z)}{\sin^2(z)} \text{d}z, \; \beta(t)=e^{it}, \; -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm working on a question,

> Let $\beta(t)=e^{it}, \; -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Find $\int_\beta \frac{\cos(z)}{\sin^2(z)} \text{d}z$.

I have
\begin{align}
\int_\beta \frac{\cos(z)}{\sin^2(z)} \text{d}z
& = \int_\beta \frac{1}{\sin^2(z)} \text{d}\sin(z) \\
& = \left[-\frac{1}{\sin(z)}\right]_\beta  \\
& = -\left(\frac{1}{\sin\left(\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}-\frac{1}{\sin\left(-\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}\right)  \\
& = -\left(\frac{1}{\sin(i)}-\frac{1}{\sin(-i)}\right) \\
& = -\frac{2}{\sin(i)}.
\end{align}
I'm not confident about the step from line 2 to line 3. Can I "evaluate over $\beta$" like that?

Comment: @FelixMarin Why is there a singularity at $z=1$? Shouldn't $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ be singular only for $z=n\pi,\;n\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Sorry. I didn’t read it carefully. You’re right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Consider the equivalent Riemann integral:

$$i\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(e^{it})}{\sin^2(e^{it})}e^{it}\d t$$As $F:t\mapsto-\csc(e^{it})$ is a continuous antiderivative of the integrand on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ it is [perfectly valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1434947/815585) by the normal fundamental theorem of calculus (applied to the real and imaginary parts) to compute this as: $$F(\pi/2)-F(-\pi/2)=-2\csc(i)$$

You may wonder - what’s the big deal with the residue theorem, then? Wouldn’t you get, for a closed loop with endpoint $z$, $F(z)-F(z)=0$? Well, in the situations where the result of the residue theorem is nontrivial (the integrand has at least one pole with nonzero residue inside the contour) you’ll find that, since $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ has no primitive in a region containing a loop around the origin, the integrand can’t have a primitive either due to its Laurent coefficients - so we must use other methods.